# setState logs older value when attempted saving it to LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, events, local-storage, onchange, setstate

Even there's a work around to solve this, I want to learn why current approach of mine below isn't successful. I wonder why local storage logs the previous value of the state even it's bonded with `setState`?

#### Explanation:

There's an input field with it's onChange function to check whenever user types and saves it to localStorage correctly.

```
<input required type="text" className="form-control" id="hotelName" name="hotelName" onChange={this.onInputChange} />

onInputChange(event) {
    localStorage.setItem('hotelCreateStep1', JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
}
```

#### Situation:

Hence, when it's intended to write the `event.target.value` to the state object before writing it to localStorage as explained below, it writes the previous value of the object (missing only the lastly typed letter or input attempt of any kind).

```
onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        hotelCreateStep1:{
            ...this.state.hotelCreateStep1,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem('hotelCreateStep1', JSON.stringify(this.state.hotelCreateStep1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` in react is asynchronous. So whenever you call `setState` then the value will not get reflected then itself. For more info about `setState` and the `callback` which it takes refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

So the issue can be resolved in two ways

- Use `setState` callback to update the `localStorage` like below

```
onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        hotelCreateStep1:{
            ...this.state.hotelCreateStep1,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    }, () => {
    localStorage.setItem('hotelCreateStep1', JSON.stringify(this.state.hotelCreateStep1))
  });;
}
```

- Or use `event.target.value` value directly in the `localStorage`

```
onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        hotelCreateStep1:{
            ...this.state.hotelCreateStep1,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    });
    localStorage.setItem('hotelCreateStep1', event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `setState()` is asynchronous. Use a callback function to achieve that.

```
onInputChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    hotelCreateStep1:{
      ...this.state.hotelCreateStep1,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }
  }, 
    () => localStorage.setItem('hotelCreateStep1', JSON.stringify(this.state.hotelCreateStep1))
  );
}
```

I have written a post about that recently. Check [here](https://karoldabrowski.com/blog/a-callback-function-of-setstate-in-reactjs/)

Comment: Thanks man, even I learned that with your answer first, I should give the accepted answer vote to the latter one, since the exact answer you provided has missing curly braces and it has applied them correctly. Happy to read your article.

Comment: It's not a problem with curly braces but with a semicolon after setItem method call. I already edited that and now it should work without curly braces as well. My bad. I am happy I could help :)

Comment: I think you misplaced the `callback` even you intended true. Cause it's placed in `setState`s curly braces so that I had to move the function out of that scope and worked that way as it still has this misplacement.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I had to open this code in my IDE and it has a misplacement indeed. I edited my post again not to leave a code containing a bug